# How to set textarea in Gridster editablely

Tags: angular, angular-gridster2

I have used Gridster 2 to create Widget in my angular application. 
but I have now a problem, in a widget there is a text area input field, but this input field can not be editable, because the whole widget is draggable.

I have try to use z-index, but it was not workling.

the code is as below:

```
<gridster-item>

 <textarea class="textarea" matInput placeholder="Enter your comment ..." [(ngModel)]="feedsComment"></textarea>
</gridster-item>
```

How can I set my widget, so that I can edit this input field.

Best Regards,

Leo

Comment: Hmm.. does the text area appear, and is it clickable?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$event.stopPropagation()` to prevent the drag while interacting with the text area.

Here is how you can use it:

```
<gridster-item>
  <div (mousedown)="$event.stopPropagation()" (touchstart)="$event.stopPropagation()">
   <textarea class="textarea" matInput placeholder="Enter your comment ..." [(ngModel)]="feedsComment"></textarea>
  </div>
</gridster-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

I still can use textarea in my dashboard.

I made a demo with textarea in dashboard.

You must check your css and dashboard options.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/my-angular-gridster2-textara

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the textarea element inside a div with class: gridster-item-content.

```
<div class="gridster-item-content">
    <textarea class="textarea" matInput placeholder="Enter your comment ..." [(ngModel)]="feedsComment"></textarea>
  </div>
```